# Google Maps - Enlarge the area around the PolyLine

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, reactjs

I am using React-Google-Maps.

I have a map with a two markers that are connected with a line.

I have event hooked on line click and that works just fine.

Issue that I am faced is the size of the line. Currently the line is small, and one need to be really precise to click it.

Solution that I have now, is to make a line Stroke bigger.
But that is a mess when I have many markers on the map, and the map is zoomed out. It becomes large group of the lines.

Here is the initialization code for the Line in the render method:

```
render: function () {
    var self = this;
    var lineOptions = {
        strokeColor: '#3497d9',
        strokeWeight: 1.5,
        geodesic: true,
        strokeOpacity: 1,
        icons: [{
            icon: {path: 'M0 0 L-4 7 L4 7 Z', scale: 1, fillColor: '#3497d9', strokeColor: '#3497d9', fillOpacity: 1},
            offset: '100px',
            repeat: '60px'
        }]
    };
```

Ideal is to have a line small, but somehow increase the clickable area around the line. Is that possible?

Comment: You could use an event listener to adjust the stroke width depending on the zoom level

Comment: How can I access the hovered line stroke? I have the event ready, but cant find the stroke for it.

Comment: Make your polyine a global variable that the event listener can access. Then you should be able to do something like `polyline.setOptions({strokeWeight: 10});`